# Datepicker angular + bootstrap 2.3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker, twitter-bootstrap-2

It seems that every datepicker out there is using bootstrap 3, can someone please provide me with angular datepicer (not datetimepicker) that is working on bootstrap 2.3 100%. Thank you

Comment: i'd suggest to use kendo datepicker, it's really simple

Comment: or chek this fiddle, might be helpful http://jsfiddle.net/cletourneau/kGGCZ/